# Can we detect which search keyword used for a particular interaction?

Tags: seo, google, analytics, keywords, search

Imagine we have a loan application website.

We want to understand out of these loan applications, the ones the go through all the way, from what search keywords did they come from?

The ones that bounce somewhere, what search keywords did they come from?

Can we do that?

I think Google Analytics can see the quantity of applications that went through all the way (by setting Google Analytics Goals on `foo.com/application/finish` link), but we cannot pinpoint to each application (imagine there's an `app_id` for each app) & say which keyword they came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be possible to get that data for organic search visitors, but it isn't anymore.  When a visitor lands on your site, Google sends a "referrer" string.  Google used to include the search terms in the referrer, but recently stopped doing so.  Now you only get that data about 25% of the time.  See http://www.notprovidedcount.com/ which tracks the stats.

If you are bidding on the traffic in Google Adwords, you can use [value track](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375447?hl=en) to dynamically insert the keyword on which you are bidding into the landing URL.   This allows you to know which keywords you are paying for are effective.   Note that the keyword you are bidding on may not match the keyword that was searched.  When you bid on broad or phrase match terms Google may show your ad for a wide variety of related keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... in theory, you could scrap the data with API and then connect it with specific application. If your apps are hosted somewhere, you can get data from there too.

Also, for better understanding which keyword to use etc. there is **[Google Trends.](https://www.google.com/trends/)**

It lets you enter multiple keywords and filter by location, search history, and category. Once you enter that information in, it'll give you results that show how much web interest there is around a particular keyword, what caused the interest (e.g., press coverage), and where the traffic is coming from -- along with similar keywords.

Comment: I don't believe that Google's APIs allow your to associate keywords with specific sessions.   The APIs only give you aggregate statistics about how many people searched for which keywords.